# How to add list data in choices in django forms?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

I have a list:

`l = [1,2,3,4,5,6]`.

Now, I want to show this list in Django admin form as a dropdown.

`list_data = forms.charField(choices = l)`

How to perform this?

Answer (score 1):

To add choices in django forms

```
CHOICES = (
    ('1', '1'),
    ('2', '1')
)
list_data = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES)
```

for more details refer this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield)

Comment: I believe it should be ChoiceField, shouldn't it?